# R CRAN submission - URLs check

Tags: r, cran

I can not find how to replicate the internal CRAN test for the URLs healthy.
It is important that this test is run only on the Debian winbuilder (yes, debian under winbuilder). As this test is not run on the Windows machine so we could NOT use the `https://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx` website service to replicate it.

The example error message from the CRAN server, as the website was moved.
Such message is producing the NOTE so the package is not automatically processed.

```
Found the following (possibly) invalid URLs:
  URL: http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/
    From: inst/doc/tinyverse.html
    Status: Error
    Message: Could not resolve host: blog.obeautifulcode.com
```

Edit:

There is a useful source with CRAN policy in this area https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/URL_checks.html

Comment: The test code has been pulled out of R itself and made into a package you can install:  https://cran.r-project.org/package=urlchecker  Other than that it is of course part of any (recent enough) R or R-devel build.

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel, on my defense I could not find any reference in the Writing R Extensions book. This is of course the expected answer, please add the regular answer so I could accept it. It is positively unbelievable to still meet you here. Wow 0% covr there we (community) need to improve it:D Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW I think you may have misread 'Debian under winbuilder'.  CRAN uses win-builder (for r-release, r-devel, ...), and CRAN uses several Debian systems.   They are not nested or co-hosted.  Different OSs, different machines (and for what it is worth in different towns / countries as far as I know).

Comment: R Under development (unstable) (2022-06-26 * ucrt)

Pretests results:
Windows: <https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/pacs_0.4.7_20220627_*/Windows/00check.log>
Status: OK
Debian: <https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/pacs_0.4.7_20220627_*/Debian/00check.log>
Status: 1 NOTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Promoting comment to answer as suggested...)

The test code has been pulled out of R itself and made into [a package you can install](https://cran.r-project.org/package=urlchecker). Other than that it is of course part of any (recent enough) R or R-devel build.

FWIW I also wrapped this into a [convenience script](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/urlUpdate.r) I call all the time on my systems.